# USRP N320 Low Band Center Frequency Shift

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, software-defined-radio

I have an USRP N320 SDR and I have an issue with 3 MHz-450 MHz band center frequency value. When I have a signal between 450 MHz and 6 GHz, I can see the actual frequency value of the signal even if I slide the center frequency but below 450 MHz, the signal is shifted negatively when I slide the center frequency.  Is there any reason and solution for this issue? Any help?

As you can see in Figure 1, the FM radio signals are correctly seen when I set the Rx Tune Frequency to 100 MHz.

## 1

[image: Figure 1]

But when I slide the Rx Tune Frequency to 110, 120,130 and 140 MHz, the FM radio signals' frequency values are also shifted. As you can see in Figure 2, 3 ,4 and 5.

## 2

[image: Figure 2]

## 3

[image: Figure 3]

## 4

[image: Figure 4]

## 5

[image: Figure 5]

Addition:

The main picture of the blocks and parameters of USRP source are below figures.

## Blocks

[image: Blocks]

## USRP Source 1

[image: Source1]

## USRP Source 2

[image: Source2]

## USRP Source 3

[image: Source3]

Also I figured out that when I applied below 450 MHz, for example 100 MHz signal and shifted center frequency with an amount, it shifts the signal double time inverse. I might not explain well but below figures does.

## 100MHz Signal at 100 MHZ center frequency

[image: 100MHz Signal at 100 MHZ center frequency]

## 100MHz Signal at 95 MHz Center frequency but appeared at 90 MHz

[image: 100MHz Signal at 95 MHz Center frequency but appeared at 90 MHz]

## 100MHz Signal at 110 MHz Center frequency but appeared at 120MHz

[image: 100MHz Signal at 110 MHz Center frequency but appeared at 120 MHz]

But When I applied a signal above 450 MHz, for example 2 GHz, it does work properly. As you can see in figure below.

## 2 GHz given signal can correctly seen in any other center frequency

[image: 2 GHz given signal can correctly seen in any other center frequency]

Comment: that's a bit surprising. Could you show us how you parameterize the USRP source?

Comment: This entry is similar to my problem.  http://ettus.80997.x6.nabble.com/USRP-users-N320-inverted-spectrum-when-tuned-below-450-MHz-td15767.html